# Remove stroke collapse - Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, comments, code-folding

I am new to Netbeans and I'd like to remove the rectangle that strokes collapse's comments.

I'd also like to remove the plus icons for collapsing the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to completely disable "code folding".

You can do this by going to Tools > Options > Editor > Folding.

Then un-check the "Enable Code Folding" checkbox:

[image]

The above screenshot is from NetBeans v13. If you are using a significantly older version of NetBeans, it's possible that this may not apply to your version (I am not sure).

If you want some different behavior, you may need to clarify your question, or use one of the other code folding options available on the same screen as the one shown above.

Comment: If I do that, all collapsed code does uncollapse & I don't want that. Rather, I wanna remove the stroke rectangle as I've said.  (:  @andrewJames

Comment: In that case, I am not sure what you mean by "the stroke rectangle". Can you clarify?

Comment: I suspect the answer is: There are 2 things you want to do, here - neither of which is possible in NetBeans: (1) When specific content is collapsed (e.g. for comments), do not display the thin grey rectangular box which is normally displayed around the collapsed content. (2) Disable the expand/collapse functionality for other specific types of content (e.g. only for code) by hiding the plus/minus boxes and leaving such content uncollapsed by default. You can do (2) on its own (but only for all types of collapsible content). You cannot combine (1) and (2) for different types of content.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the frame around the collapsed comment in the settings, or rather not remove it, but change the color so that it merges with your background.
Tools-> Options -> (tab) Font and color -> Highlighting -> and in the Categories there is an item "Border of the collapsed code"
Change the text color and background color, click apply and see the result!)

Убрать рамку вокруг свёрнутого комментария можно в настройках, вернее не убрать а поменять цвет, чтобы она сливалась с вашим фоном.
Сервис-> Параметры -> (вкладка) Шрифт и цвет  -> Подсветка  -> и в Категориях есть пункт " Граница свёрнутого кода"
Меняете цвет текста и цвет фона, нажимает применить и смотрим результат !)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).